# Is It Safe To Use A Fusion Torch In Atmosphere?

Tags: space-travel

Would it be safe (little to no ill effects) to use a magnetic confinement fusion torch in earth's atmosphere? Thinking of using it for a shuttle.

Comment: This depends on a _lot_ of variables.  How much mass is being lifted?  What is the propellant?  What is being used as the fusion fuel?  "Torchship" is a broad category.

Comment: As written you have not enough detail to produce an answer.  You're asking about a fictional device without defining any of it's physical parameters, it's energy output and other characteristics.

Comment: @The Imperial right now your question is flagged as unclear. Please edit your question to address the key concerns noted: 1. what is a fusion torch? 2. how does it work? 3. what range does its use affect? It's likely to be closed if a better understanding of what your after isn't forthcoming!

Comment: If you mean _in_ atmosphere, i.e. to replace a jet engine, then this is an answerable question (though it would help to specify whether you're taking about much bigger vehicles, etc, or somebody will ask you why bother?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes... for a certain definition of "use"

There will be no ill effects to turning on a magnetic-confinement fusion engine in a planet's atmosphere because *there will be no effects at all,* beyond wasting fuel and spraying small amounts of radioactive tritium into the atmosphere (if you're using D-T fusion). Fusion reactors don't work in atmospheres.

Magnetic-confinement fusion works by using magnetic fields to contain and compress incredibly hot plasma in order to give the nuclei within the plasma any chance of fusing together and producing more heat. This is possible because plasma, by definition, is a stew of charged particles- positively-charged ions and negatively-charged electrons- and charged particles can be controlled using magnetic fields. Air, however, is composed of neutrally-charged molecules that do not react to magnetic fields in any way relevant to this question. Try to fire up your fusion drive in an atmosphere, and the heat in any plasma you try to inject into the reactor will almost instantly be absorbed and dissipated by the air, preventing any fusion from taking place.

Of course, it's possible to put a fusion reactor in a vacuum chamber, and indeed, this is what all the teams working on magnetic confinement fusion do. However, a fusion drive in a vacuum chamber is a rocket in a very sturdy metal box, and won't be able to go very far. It may manage to structurally compromise the chamber, and it it isn't destroyed by the collapsing vacuum chamber, air will rush in and quench the reaction.

Answer (score 3):

(N.B. This can be improved if the question is clarified.)

#### Maybe

There are a bunch of negative consequences to using any sort of rocket in-atmosphere.  Our current chemical rockets can spew a mix of [terribly toxic propellants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsymmetrical_dimethylhydrazine), which can be even worse if they crash.  They also [punch holes in the ozone layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_depletion_by_rocket_launches).

Fusion torches are generally reserved (in fiction) for propelling very large spacecraft, due to the tremendous energies developed and the trouble of confining them.  Even assuming that your magnetic "confinement" is powerful enough to direct what is essentially a continuing nuclear explosion on a smaller scale, there are still guaranteed complications:

- **Blindness** - fusion reactions are very bright.  For reference, see the sun.  (Don't actually see it, because you will go blind.)  If you go streaking through the atmosphere of an inhabited planet with one of these, people are going to have to learn quickly not to look near a ship when it's lighting off its drive.
- **Deafness** - think a normal rocket launch is loud?  Imagine something accelerating its propellant to substantial C-fractions in-atmosphere.  It will be very, very loud anywhere near this ship.
- **Irradiation** - fusion's a lot cleaner than fission, obviously, but it still produces [high energy neutrons](http://mafija.fmf.uni-lj.si/seminar/files/2016_2017/seminar-dijana-m-ib.pdf), which can cause secondary irradiation, as well as producing gamma wave-energy photons directly.  If you light off a contained fusion bomb in atmosphere, radioactive byproducts will be created.  In addition, depending on what your propellant is, it could be irradiated before it's expelled, further polluting the atmosphere.

All of these are potentially manageable side effects, but it would depend on the frequency of use, the size of the shuttle, the fusion fuel being used, the location of the launch, the propellant...

Thus, a very definite *maybe*.